# Jquery UI Datepicker disable specific days and all (Mondays&Tuesday)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to  disable specific days and all (Mondays&Tuesday) for example

```
 var array = ["2020-03-14","2020-03-15","2020-03-16"]

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
              var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
              var day = date.getDay();
              if (day != 1 && day != 2)
                  return [true]
              else if  ( array.indexOf(string) == -1)
                  return [ true]
              else
                  return [ false]

        }
    });
```

but it disable only **"2020-03-16"** what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
jQuery(function($){
  var arr = [
    "2020-03-14",
    "2020-03-15",
    "2020-03-16"
  ];
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(dt){
      var dStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
      var day = dt.getDay();
      var result = [false, ""];
      if (day != 1 && day != 2){
        result = [true, "available"];
      }
      if(arr.indexOf(dStr) >= 0){
        result = [true, ""];
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

> **beforeShowDay**
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> - `[0]`: `true`/`false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> - `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or `""` for the default presentation
> - `[2]`: an optional popup tooltip for this date

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

You must return the right array.

Comment: If you can help also , how can I get date and time in input after click on it , http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/258/